# What services can I turn off to trigger a second application attempt?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Hadoop YARN includes a configuration to modify how many times an application can be started: `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts`.

I am interested in hitting this limit to observe how the system may fail, and I want to be able to do it without modifying code. To mimic production scenarios, I would like to turn off other Hadoop services to cause a second attempt of the application.

What services can I turn off during the application run to trigger another application attempt?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, just close storage services(hosting your source data or target data). For example, hdfs service, hive service, etc.